# Problem with creating default cylinders for 3D Printing

Tags: 3d-printing

I am learning the basics of 3D printing, and so far the Print3D add on is amazing.
And I have successfully created a model that was printed.

But a problem, that happens all the time, really takes a massive amount of time to repair is this:

When I use the create mesh function to make a cylinder, the Print3D addon always reports that they have intersecting faces.
I can create multiple cylinders, and random faces are always reported intersecting.
If I make a duplicate of the offending mesh, Print3D then will always report different faces other than the problem ones from the original are intersecting.

Once I try to repair all these intersecting faces, every once in a while, there will be some that it is impossible to fix the intersecting face.  I could delete all the problem vertices/edges/faces, create a single new face, divide it just once, and put the new vertices in the exact same coordinates, and the exact intersecting faces shows up again.  When this happens, the only solution I found to this was to delete the entire mesh, and create a new cylinder.

Is there a setting I have off, or maybe a glitch in the program or add on?

Comment: For both ngon and triangular fan filled end caps?

Comment: I'm new to the program, so I'm not sure exactly what an ngon is.  It's just, I click the button to create a primitive cylinder, then resize it to 4mm X 4mm X 4mm, and I go to the Print3D add on to see what it says.  Sometimes it will be two or more faces on the side, sometimes an end cap and a side.  I have yet to notice a pattern.